# Polymorphic Routes in Rails - in views

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have Comment as a polymorphic model.

It is attached to Post, Review, etc.

I also have an action in CommentsController, called `test`.

I have my routes setup, so `test_post_comment_path` works (to call the `test` action in the CommentsController).

The problem is, in my partial view, I want that route to be able to change, based on the current action, ie. it is `test_post_comment_path` when on a Post and `test_review_comment_path` when on a Review.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I decided to just use an if statement in the view, based on if the current action was present, such as if @post or if @review

Comment: Look over the polymorphic path helpers.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/PolymorphicRoutes.html

Answer (score 5):

The correct way to do this is with polymorphic_url...

Comment: awesome, I was just looking for that =)

Answer (score 1):

Just use two different paths?

What I mean is: you don't want to put so much logic inside routes.

If routes try to do something more than routing, the first time somethings goes wrong you'll be in serious trouble.

In your partial view, the logic to create specific links or other html comment stuff should go in a helper.

Comment: I want the logic to change in the view itself - I'm just not sure how

Answer (score 0):

Something like this: 
(in your partial view)

```
@commentable.each |commentable|
    test_#{commentable.class.to_s.downcase}_comment_path
end
```

if it is 'post' then it will generate 'test_post_comment_path', if it is review, it will generate test_review_comment_path