# How to get a named route from a class in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have a common partial for index where i want to insert some links.
On this links i would like to use the named_routes, like

```
link_to "Say hi",things_path(:param1=>:hello, :params2=>:there)
```

but i dont know if things_path is users_path, places_path or reviews_path, because this partial is shared for all controllers. There is any way to get the named route associated to the class or the current controller. 
I want something like this

```
link_to "Say hi", path_of(@current_class)(:param1=>:hello, :params2=>:there)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A path helper like cars_path is ultimately just a shortcut to setting :controller, :action and other params like :id.  If you want to make the controller always equal to the current controller you can just say

link_to "Say hi", :action => "index", :param1=>:hello, :params2=>:there

Because the :controller option is omitted, it will be assumed to be the current controller.

Comment: I know. Even more: Since i am already on index action, i even can ommit controller and action, and the link will point to the current action. But the shortcut has some syntax sugar i love. And im thinking in future applications of this approach on mi app.

Answer (score 1):

There are several approaches to this. The simplest thing is to rely on polymorphic routing, such as: `link_to "Say hi", @my_object`. In this case rails will look at the class of `@my_object` and its current state (`new_record?`) and use the appropriate route and restful action. Assuming your partial is named `_foo.html.erb` then this can be as simple as

```
link_to 'Say hi', foo
```

... which is pretty awesome. This question has been asked before, here: [Polymorphic Routes in Rails - in views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348027/polymorphic-routes-in-rails-in-views) but I guess it's hard to find answers without knowing the magic words "polymorphic routing" :-)