# Rails Variable Polymorphic Route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I want to pass in a variable to a route in a partial.

The model in question look like this:

```
 model Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :dogs
   has_many :cats
```

The path I want is either:

```
   <%= link_to "#{foo.name}", foo_dogs_path(foo) %>
   <%= link_to "#{foo.name}", foo_cats_path(foo) %>
```

I want to use either "dogs" or "cats" depending on a passed-in variable animal_type.  I know I need to use [Polymorphic Routes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html) but I'm having trouble working out the syntax for this scenario.

Comment: Are you having trouble in the routes or the view? I haven't tried this, but it looks like [polymorphic_url](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/PolymorphicRoutes/polymorphic_url) might be your answer based on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2246782/1103543).

Comment: @ConstableJoe - In the view.  Yes, I believe you're right that polymorphic_url is the answer, I just need help with the specific syntax.

Comment: Are you trying to have the link be `/cats` or `/dogs`, or `/animals`? I believe `polymorphic_url` does the latter but not the former, though I've personally never used polymorphic URLs before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
link_to "dogs", [foo, :dogs]
```

in rails 3 it works

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about polymorphic routes, but for something this simple you could always do:

```
<% if foo.class.name == "Cat" %>
    <%= link_to "#{foo.name}", foo_cats_path(foo) %>
<% else %>
    <%= link_to "#{foo.name}", foo_dogs_path(foo) %>
<% end %>
```

It might not be super elegant and I'm sure there's a niftier way to do it in Rails if you keep looking, but it gets the job done.

Comment: The `foo.class.name` syntax I think is right, but double check me on it.  But the logic works.